# C# cosmos file IO and directories

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, operating-system, command

Does anybody know how to make file Input and Output and how to create directories in C# cosmos?

Comment: From the FAQ: `How do I write to a file in COMOS?
You can't, yet.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [technical FAQ](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TechnicalFAQ&referringTitle=FAQ) it's described how you prepare a disk image for Cosmos. Then you should be able to use at least some of the standard methods of file input.

File output is not yet supported.

Comment: @FrewCen: As the project uses Visual Studio I imagine that most have. That is not a problem, there are Linux distributions that boots from a CD, like KNOPPIX: http://www.knoppix.org/

Comment: @FrewCen: You don't, if you can find another way to accomplish what's described in the FAQ.

Comment: @FrewCen: I don't see why C++ would be better for writing IO classes than C#. You can't use the C++ standard libraries anyway. If you write the routines yourself you can use any disk format you like, but continuing on the already existing plugs would probably be easier.

Comment: Yes, I will try it with C++ std... If will it be problem, i will use inline assembly and assembler file IO.